# how can i set a variable as a key in mongoose with the findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

```
let VARIABLE = "last_name"<br>
let change_to = "lee"

userModel.findOneAndUpdate(<br>
    {first_name: "luke"},<br>
    {$set: {VARIABLE:change_to}},<br>
    {new:true},  
)
```

Question: How can I use a variable within `$set`? As of now the `findOneAndUpdate()` is assuming that a VARIABLE key within this objects exists ->

```
{<br>
   _id:123,<br>
   first_name: 'luke',<br>
   VARIABLE: '123'<br>
}
```

When in fact it doesn't. Could anyone please help me figure out this problem?

I'm using Mongoose, NodeJs & Postman

No error messages, the program actually works but nothing updates because VARIABLE doesn't exist within the user object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`es2015` computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
var a = 'name'
var b = { [a]: 'Bob' }
console.log(b)
```

```
let VARIABLE = "last_name"
userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {first_name: "luke"},
  {$set: {[VARIABLE]:change_to}},
  {new:true},  
)
```